# Run a function when an HTML5 Audio Element has played a certain %

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Is there any way to run a predefined function when an HTML5 Audio element has played a certain amount (such as 50%, 80%)? Let's assume I know the size of the file and anything else.

```
<div class="audio-player" style="display:none;">
  <audio id="music" preload="auto">
    <source src="/path/to/my.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  </audio>
</div>
```

I'm already using Javascript to play/pause this audio.

```
function aud_play_pause(_id) {
  var audio = document.getElementById("music");
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.pause();
 }
}
```

So let's say I had a function `halfway()` to tell if someone had listened to half the song, is there any way I can run this when the track reaches 50%? Even if this is an estimate, that's fine. I would also like to avoid the use of any frameworks, as I don't need any additional functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a better way, but I could see you using the "duration" and "currentTime" properties of media elements in HTML5.
Untested, but this might get you unstuck:

```
function check(){
  var duration = audioElement.duration;
  var currentTime = audioElement.currentTime;
  if( currentTime / duration >= 0.5 ){
    halfway()
  }
}

setInterval(check, 1000) //run this checker on an interval
```

Comment: Thanks, Liam! This works, but will run `halfway()` for every second past the halfway point - an easy fix!

Answer (score 1):

What about using a setTimout ?

like with :

```
var relativeStopPosition = 0.5; // half-way
function aud_play_pause(_id) {
  var audio = document.getElementById("music");
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
    setTimeout(audio.pause.bind(audio), Date.now + relativeStopPosition * 1000* audio.duration ) ;
  } else {
    audio.pause();
 }
}
```